# ActiveAdmin create/update controller

Tags: activeadmin

In my create method in controller, how to decide which to use: create! or super?
Also, what's the difference between

```
   super do |format|
```

and

```
   super do |success, failure|
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveAdmin uses InheritedResources.  The [InheritedResources README](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources#overwriting-actions) explains "calling super is not very readable. That's why all methods have aliases". The bottom of that section also shows how `update! do |success, failure|` provides a more compact alternative to `update! do |format|` when you want to override the default success/failure behaviour.